# How to cd into a directory as part of shell script and do a word count of files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to get the latest folder inside my directory in machineB and machineC. So I came up with the below command which will find me the latest folder inside -

```
`/bat/data/snapshot`
```

And that latest folder will be in the form of `YYYYMMDD`. Below is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2
```

Now `dir1` will look like in `machineB` as -

```
/bat/data/snapshot/20131222
```

And `dir2` will look like in `machineC` as -

```
/bat/data/snapshot/20131222
```

Now I need to `cd` into these two directory and do a word count of files and store them in length1 and length2 variable -

```
ls | wc -l
```

I thought I can do this but I thought before that I need to cd into those two directory and then do a word count -

```
echo $dir1
echo $dir2

length1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} ls | wc -l "$dir1")
length2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} ls | wc -l "$dir2")

echo $length1
echo $length2
```

So now I am not sure how to do cd into those two directory and then do a `ls` and find the count of files as part of that shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to write a script rather than trying to pass a big ugly command via `ssh` arguments. It becomes very difficult to execute complex commands via ssh arguments because ssh joins all the arguments into a space separated string, and then re-splits them on the remote end.

Now, using a script isn't as bad as it sounds, and is actually quite simple since you can pass the script over STDIN.

```
function host_file_count() {
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no david@"$1" bash -s <<'EOI'
  dir_last="$(ls -dt1 /bat/data/snapshot/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n 1)"
  count="$(ls -1 "$dir_last"/ | wc -l)"
  echo "$(hostname): $dir_last=$count"
EOI
}
host_file_count machineB
host_file_count machineC
```

Basically this just feeds the script into the STDIN of `ssh` which in turn passes to STDIN of `bash -s` on the remote host.
The other advantage of doing it this way is that you don't have to perform multiple `ssh` commands to get the result.

---

Note that many will tell you not to parse `ls`. So below is another script which does the same but without using `ls`.

```
function host_file_count() {
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no david@"$1" bash -s <<'EOI'
  dirs=( /bat/data/snapshot/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ) # get a list of matching directories
  dir_last="${dirs[${#dirs[@]} - 1]}" # get the last item in the list
  files=( "$dir_last"/* ) # get the list of files in directory
  count="${#files[@]}" # size of that list
  echo "$(hostname): $dir_last=$count"
EOI
}
host_file_count machineB
host_file_count machineC
```

---

*note: both of these are completely untested, there may be minor errors, but the principle stands*

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. I am little bit rusty in bash scripting.. How do I am supposed to call host_file_count() method in my shell script keeping in mind as I have few constants declared.

Comment: It's there at the bottom. `host_file_count machineB` `host_file_count machineC`.

Answer (score 0):

Your local shell in interpreting the pipe, plus you've got the variable on the wrong command:

```
len1=$( ssh ... user@host sh -c "ls '$dir1' | wc -l" )
```

Comment: still it doesn't work and I am getting  length as 0 always..

Comment: It works fine if I remove sh -c and keep everything as it is.. Any idea why?

Comment: @TechGeeky the `sh -c` is implied. `ssh` on the remote host basically passes all the arguments through a `sh -c`, so specifying it is unnecessary. With it as is, you get into lots of issues with ssh and wordsplitting (it's a complex ugly mess).